# How to create resources for the elements in a list is part of another list in Terraform?

Tags: list, filter, conditional-statements, terraform, resources

How to create resources for the elements in a list is part of another list in Terraform?

```
variable names {
  default   = ["vk", "sb", "vc", "ss"]
}

variable subnames {
  default   = ["vk", "sb"]
}
```

expected output is to print all names that are part of subnames.

Comment: How about using [setintersection](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setintersection) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do it

```
output test {
    value   = [for name in var.names: name if contains(var.subnames, name)]
}
```

if this is some resource instead of output, the same statement can be used in for_each. Output does not support for_each